# ValidationError "password can't be blank" when calling updateAttribute in Loopback

Tags: mongodb, validation, loopbackjs

In my Loopback REST api, I need to update a single attribute isPublic on the Member model that extends User. I'm unable to do it using updateAttribute. I get a `ValidationError` saying `password can't be blank`

```
Member.findById(memberId, {fields:{id: true, isPublic: true}}, function (err, member) {
      // this gives ValidationError
      // member.updateAttribute('isPublic', !member.isPublic, cb);
});
```

Using update() works:

```
// this works
Member.update({id: memberId}, {isPublic: !member.isPublic}, cb);
```

But is there a way to without grabbing password for the member instance to call updateAttribute on

Comment: I have no idea about `loopbckjs`. But your `Member.update({id: memberId}, {isPublic: !member.isPublic}, cb);` query is wrong. It will replace the whole record with `isPublic` field. You should use `$set` if there is some existing field present in the record.

Comment: Is this in a remote hook?

Comment: @RaymondCamden : Yes, it's in a remote hook

Answer (score 1):

No. Because you get user with two fields and password is undefined in instance you get.

And there is no `update` method. It is `updateAll`.
Your second way has a better performance.

Comment: `updateAll` is same as the `update` method https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/dao.js#L2285-L2290